# Entered TextField values disappeared while rotating device in appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator

I have an issue with screen orientation. The scenario is that, Suppose if there is 5 Text fields, and we entering different values for each Text field. After that, while we rotating the device, The 5th value got placed in all the Text fields and vice versa. if we entered only 3 out of 5 text fields, the last value in the field(null value) got placed in all the text fields.

Any help will be deeply appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Post some code/markup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding 'orientation' in below line for all  in the tiapp.xml file,

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
```

i think it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen that before in the 5 years working with Appcelerator. Do you have a test case/code that replicates what you are doing? Maybe someone else testing would help...

Ray